# relationship with a sliced and casted value of the column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there any way to create a relationship like this (example data) between Parent and Child based on `parent_id` and `id` respectively:

**Parent**
parent_id: "A1234"
name: "Parent Name"

**Child**
id: 1234

how can I add the foreign key to the `Child`? The `parent_id` is a `String`. Is there a way to slice it and then cast to `Integer`?

---

**Edit:**
Also what if the situation happens other way round:

**Child:**
child_id: "A1234"

**Parent:**
parent_letter: "A"
parent_id: 1234

would that be something like:
`primaryjoin=(child_id == (Parent.parent_letter + str(Parent.parent_id)))`

what would the `remote_side` look like? or the entire `relationship`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Creating Custom Foreign Conditions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/join_conditions.html#creating-custom-foreign-conditions) section of documentation. Using the `cast`, the relationship can be setup for the model below:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    parent_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

    parent = relationship(
        Parent,
        primaryjoin=("A" + cast(id, String) == Parent.parent_id),
        foreign_keys=id,
        remote_side=Parent.parent_id,
        backref="children",
        # uselist=False,  # use in case of one-to-one relationship
    )
```

In this case you can *query* for `Parent.children` or `Child.parent`:

```
p1 = session.query(Parent).get('A1234')
print(p1)
print(p1.children)

c1 = session.query(Child).get(1234)
print(c1)
print(c1.parent)
```

However you would still not be able to *create* relationship items like below:

```
p = Parent(
    parent_id='A3333', name='with a child',
    children=[Child(name='will not work')]
)
session.add(p)
session.commit()  # this will fail
```

**Edit-1**: For the alternative case you mention in your comments and edit, following relationship definition should work (obviously, the model is defined differently as well):

```
parent = relationship(
    Parent,
    primaryjoin=(
        foreign(child_id) ==
        remote(Parent.parent_letter + cast(Parent.parent_id, String))
    ),
    backref="children",
    uselist=False,
)
```

Comment: so if I would like to do it the other way round (child_id is an Integer and parent_letter is a String and parent_id is an Integer) would I just do something like: `primaryjoin=(child_id == parent_letter + str(parent_id))` ?

Comment: I guess so, but I am not sure on which tables are those columns you mention in your comment?

Comment: Child_id on child table and the rest on Parent table

Comment: But if both `child_id` and `parent_id` are `Integer`s, would not they be very simple `ForeignKey`? In which case what is the role of the `parent_letter`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it properly. Child_id is something like "A1234". Parent_letter: "A" parent_id: 1234

Comment: Yes, you can do it, but in this case, why not do same two columns on the `Child` table and have a proper foreign key covering two columns?

Comment: What my remote_side be though? Yeah at some point I'll just do that. For now need a quick solution

Comment: Your first comment mentions that `child_id` is `Integer`. Is it not now?

Comment: let me just edit my question with what I mean and you can edit your answer with this additional part. thanks for help again. I just get rid off the comments afterwards

Comment: You can do the following: change `primaryjoin` to be `primaryjoin=(
            foreign(child_id) ==
            remote(Parent.parent_letter + cast(Parent.parent_id, String))
        ),` and remove completely `foreign_keys` and `remote_side` arguments to `realtionship(...)`

Comment: Two differences to the solution you proposed for the alternative case: 1) you still need `cast` to make sure proper `SQL` is generated for navigating relationships; 2) using `foreign` and `remote` (imported from `sqlalchemy.orm` makes other arguments redundant.